# How to properly adjust the movement of cells in the table

Tags: swift, xcode

The user's task is to arrange the cells in order. (for example a child)

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFHfV.png)

move cells using:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ...
    table.dragDelegate = self
    table.dropDelegate = self
    table.dragInteractionEnabled = true
    ...
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    usersChooseOrder.insert(usersChooseOrder.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row), at: destinationIndexPath.row)
}
    
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem] {
    print("itemsForBeginning")
    return []
}
    
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, performDropWith coordinator: UITableViewDropCoordinator) {
    print("  coordinator")
}
```

At any time, you can check the correctness of the placement by pressing the "Finish" button and the correct cells, which in their place are colored green.
Tell me in which direction to look to implement the following:

the green cell should be fixed in place and not move anymore, neither with your finger, nor due to the movement of other cells. Those. if 5 is moved to place 2 under 4, then 2 should go to place 6, and 4 should remain in place.
And if we move 5 to place 6, then 6 and 1 rise above and 5 is obtained above 4.

I would be glad to any hint.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> the green cell should be fixed in place and not move anymore

In `canMoveRowAt` check the index of the green cell and return false:

```swift
if indexPath.row == indexOfGreenCell{
   return false
} else {
   return true
}
```

For the rest use this function. Note that you'll have to edit it to make the green item stay still.

```swift
    func refreshIndex( sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, destinationIndexPath: IndexPath){
        let source = sourceIndexPath.row //Item to move
        let destination = destinationIndexPath.row //destination
        
        if source < destination {
            var startIndex = source + 1
            let endIndex = destination
            var startOrder = (numbers[source])
            while startIndex <= endIndex {
                numbers[startIndex] = startOrder
                startOrder = startOrder + 1
                startIndex = startIndex + 1
                
            }
            
            numbers[source] = startOrder
            
        } else if destination < source {
            var startIndex = destination
            let endIndex = source
            var startOrder = (numbers[destination]) + 1
            let newOrder = numbers[destination]
            while startIndex <= endIndex {
                numbers[startIndex] = startOrder
                startOrder = startOrder + 1
                startIndex = startIndex + 1
            }
            numbers[source] = newOrder
        }
    }
```

call it inside the following function:

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
I almost understood everything ... Just what is
(numbers [source]) and (numbers [destination])
?

Comment: no problem! numbers[source] is the item you're moving. When you move it you constantly assign to it the value of startOrder. numbers[destination] is the item in the position you want your item to be moved

Comment: Hello!
Did I understand correctly that the refreshIndex method adjusts the movement of cells when one of them is dragged? But at the same time, he does not take into account the position of the green cell and the fact that when moving neighboring cells, it must remain in its place. After all, the green index is not passed to the refreshIndex method